# Change z-order of bars in an Aspose slide following upgrade?

Tags: aspose, aspose-slides

We have a bar chart with two series, that is loaded from a template. Previously we used v8.0 of Aspose.Slides, and have recently upgraded to the latest version (v14.6). Without making any changes to the logic (aside from class name changes necessary for compilation), the first bar which was previously drawn over/above the other bar is now being drawn under it.

Is there are way to programmatically adjust the order or height of the bars, so that one is always above the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could get was to change the order of series that were being added to the chart. The first series is rendered first, then later series are rendered in order over it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any feature available in Aspose.Slides or MS PowerPoint for that matter to change the Z-Index on a data point in a bar chart. You can contact Aspose Support to get more information regarding change in behavior between 2 versions.